# How to put LINQ condition on partial view used by all the views in razor MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have one partial view **_Layout** which is used by all the views, and each view is a strongly-typed view. 
Now my query is, each user who logins belongs to a department, and I wish to hide some of the tabs (from the partial view) when a user of a particular department logins the website, and displaying all the tabs for all other users.
I have tried putting LINQ query to get department name in all the ActionResult, storing in a ViewBag and putting a condition in shared view:

```
      @if (ViewBag.Department == "CUSTOMER SUPPORT")
      {
          //View all the tabs
      }
      else
      {
          //Restricted tabs
      }
```

For this I have to declare ViewBag, and make LINQ query in every ActionResult to hide/show the tabs even when the user navigates to different pages from the tabs being displayed on shared view.

**I've also tried** making the partial view strongly typed so that the model holds the value of department name, but it doesn't work when I navigate to another strongly-typed view.

Can I somehow declare a variable globally to store department's name and call on the shared view instead of declaring on every ActionResult?
Or directly getting Department's name on the shared view without controller, like using LINQ on shared view?

Answer (score 2):

If i don't get you wrong and your tabs are something like a navigation and not content, this could help you: [Use of child action in layout view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45809466/3351148)

1. Create separate view for navigation with dedicated view model.
2. Create an action for above with which fills the view model (decide which tabs to show)
3. Call the above action from within the layout view using @Html.Action

Answer (score 1):

You can create action filter for this.

```
public class SomeMsgAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
        }

        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Department= "Department";
        }
}
```

Then you can decorate your controller with this attribute.

```
[SomeMsg]
public class MyController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you provide an actual example of how this will work for the OP because currently I do not believe this answers the question fully